# Techniques for handling opening a new tab and ensuring web accessibility with WCAG 3.2

Tags: html, css, wcag

WCAG 3.2 indicates that content should be provided in a predictable format (https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20-20161007/consistent-behavior.html) and that subsequently when new a new tab is opened on a click that the user is made aware of this.

I have a webpage with a list of many links that open in a new tab. W3C recommends that either this is indicated in the link text or an indicator is provided on hover/focus. However, because of the extensive amount of links on the same page that require this, providing these options would significantly disrupt the design/UI. Are there are other less visually intrusive ways to achieve this conformance without providing a pop-up or text warning for each link?

Also, are there other accessibility issues related to opening new windows/tabs?

Comment: [Cross-posted to UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/123625/17023)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may depend on the [level of conformance](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance.html#uc-conformance-requirements-head) you're trying to achieve. Most companies (and most country laws) require AA conformance.  In fact, the guidelines say that AAA conformance should **not** be required.

> *Note 2:* It is not recommended that Level AAA conformance be required as a general policy for entire sites because it is not possible to satisfy all Level AAA Success Criteria for some content.

However, that does not mean you shouldn't consider **some** of the AAA requirements.  For example, having color contrast that's greater than 4.5:1 ([1.4.6 Contrast (Enhanced)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#visual-audio-contrast7)) or making sure your link text makes sense by itself rather than relying on the context around it ([2.4.9 Link Purpose (Link Only)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#navigation-mechanisms-link)) are both great enhancements above AA conformance.

With regards to links opening in new windows, that falls under [3.2.5 Change on Request](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#consistent-behavior-no-extreme-changes-context), which is a AAA conformance.  So depending on the level of conformance you're trying to achieve, you might not have to conform to it.

If you only had a handful of links scattered throughout your site that opened in a new window, it would be nice to have a visual indicator that shows the link will open in a new window, and to convey that same information to screen readers.  (See [H83: Using the target attribute to open a new window on user request and indicating this in link text (HTML)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/H83#H83-examples) as an example.  You could also use an icon instead of text, but make sure the icon has the `alt` attribute or that you provide context to a screen reader via [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label), [`aria-labelledby`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-labelledby), or [visually hidden text](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/)).

But if you do that, and then you have a page where most of the links go to a new window, the page might look cluttered with all the extra information.  This is where you'd have to be careful.  If you decide to have a general comment on that one page that says that all links open in a new window so that you don't need an icon next to each link, then you'd be failing [WCAG 3.2.4 Consistent Identification](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#consistent-behavior-consistent-functionality), which is a AA requirement.  That is, you'd have some pages with "new window" icons next to the links and another page without it.

So you need to decide **if** you want to indicate that a link opens in a new window (a AAA requirement) or not.  As mentioned earlier, implementing some AAA requirements is a good thing.  Just be consistent.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed response. this really sheds some light on the issue for me.